# How to bypass nginx proxy a list of IPS

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, whitelist

I have an Nginx config with the redirect to holding pages:

```
    location / {
        ...
        if ($setholdingpage = 'True') {
        rewrite (^.*$) /holding-page last;
        }
           proxy_pass $backend;
    }
```

Also, I have a list of IPs that should be whitelisted and not redirected to holding pages. How it's possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Nginx [geo module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) to create a variable based upon client IP address, you can specify individual IP addresses or CIDR ranges:

```
geo $bypassip {
  default 0;

  64.233.160.0/19 1;
  66.102.0.0/20 1;
}
```

Then override your variable if the IP matches one in your list:

```
if ($bypassip = 1){
  set $setholdingpage False;
}
```

I use a similar setup to block certain geographic regions but still allow Google crawlers to access my site.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I used this approach and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `allow` `deny` directives.

If I get you correct the whitelist will be your `$setholdingpage` variable in some sort?

try this

```
server {

error_page 403=@holding;

location / {
  allow 127.0.0.1;
  allow 192.168.1.0/24;
  deny all;

  proxy_pass http://backend;

}

location /@holding {
  root /path/to/your/holding/html;
  index holdingv1.html;
}

}
```

This will send the non-whitelisted IPs to the error-page you specified. The error_page can be in the `location` as well.

Not tested but this should do the trick.

References:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html#allow

Comment: Thanks for the help. Possibly, this is a good approach, but I used "geo" and this approach works.